# onsen ui : align center

Tags: css, onsen-ui

hi i want to align center horizontally - but its not happening

here is my code :

```
<ons-row class="center bordertop1 grey1" style="margin-top:10px;text-align:center !important;">
                    <ons-col class="center borderright1 grey1" ng-click="" style="" ><ons-row style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;"><img  ng-src="img/icon/icon1.png"  /></ons-row><ons-row  class="center">icon1 </ons-row></ons-col>
                    <ons-col class="center borderright1 borderbottom1" style=""><ons-row style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;"><img  class="center"  ng-src="img/icon/icon2.png"  /></ons-row><ons-row class="center" style="margin-bottom:10px;"   >option 2{{member.followercount}}</ons-row></ons-col>
                    <ons-col class="center borderbottom1" style=""><ons-row class="center" style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;"><img  ng-src="img/icon/icon3.png"  /></ons-row><ons-row class="center" style="margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center !important;">option 3 </ons-row></ons-col>
                </ons-row>
```

i also tried style="text-align: center;"

not working

help me 
Regards

Comment: please show the external css file as well, a live example will be even better, but it's hard to tell from what we've got here.
anyway, <ons-row> has align attribute, you can read about at: http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html, there are examples too...go to "Layouting" on the page.

Answer (score 3):

Either way, I'd try manipulating the css or the styles to add properties like:

```
width: 100%;
```

or

```
margin: 10px auto;
```